# $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I wonder if there's a connection between $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$ since one can also see $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm just looking for general thoughts about this. Sorry if this question is not specific enough.

Can we say that the topology on $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ is coarser than the topology on $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$? My idea:

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ be in $V(f)$ for a polynomial $f = c_0 + ... + c_nX^n$ in $\mathbb{C}[X]$. Write $z = x + iy$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and similarly $c_i = a_i + i b_i$. Then 
$$c_0 + ... + c_nz^n = 0 \Leftrightarrow a_o + i b_0 + ... + (a_n + i b_n)(x + iy)^n = 0 \Leftrightarrow f_r(x,y) + i f_i(x,y) = 0$$
for some real polynomials $f_r$ and $f_i$. So 
$$z \in V(f) \Leftrightarrow (x,y) \in V(f_r, f_i).$$ Showing that $V(f)$ is also closed in $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Not really, $\Bbb{C}[x]$ is very different to $\Bbb{R}[X,Y]$.

Comment: @reuns I added something to my post, do you think what I wrote is correct?

Comment: Yes this is the idea of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_restriction but $\Bbb{A^2_R}$ is a topology on $\Bbb{C}^2$ not on $\Bbb{R}^2$ (for example $V(X^2+1)$ is  empty in $\Bbb{R}^2$)

Comment: Cool, thank you @reuns! Do you mean that $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No. $V(X-i)$ is closed only in $\Bbb{A^2_C}$ not in $\Bbb{A^2_R}$, but $V(X-1)$ is the same set in both. What you are looking at is $\Bbb{A^2_R(R)}$, the subset of real points (there is also the $Spec(\Bbb{R}[X,Y])$ space where we put $(i,0)$ and $(-i,0)$ is the same "bag" $V(X^2+1,Y)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that using the classical topology, $\mathbb{R}^2\cong \mathbb{C}$. Indeed, these spaces are isomorphic as real vector spaces. However, if we use the Zariski topology, $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ are quite different. Indeed, $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ has the finite complement topology, whereas this is not the case for $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Of course, the differences between $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ are more substantial than just the non-homeomorphic topologies. They have distinct dimensions as topological spaces (in the algebraic sense) -  the former is dimension $2$ while the latter is dimension $1$. Lastly, at the level of rings of functions, we see that the affine coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ while the affine coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ is $\mathbb{C}[x]$. The significant differences in these rings are reflected in the significant differences in the topologies of the spaces.

It's worth mentioning that $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ since as sets they have the same cardinality and are equipped with the finite complement topology. Also, comparing rings of functions we see that $A(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}})=\mathbb{R}[x]$ while $A(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}})=\mathbb{C}[x]$. Since $\mathbb{R}[x]\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{C}[x]$, we see that these spaces in some sense differ only by a "base change."

So, actually the real affine line is closer to the complex affine line in this context.